# Show that a point is not contained in a region defined by two circles

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

Let $w_0$ a point in the complex plane, and $w,w^*$ two points on the same line that passes through $w_0$. The two points are equi-distanced from $w_0$ and on the two different sides of the line.

Let $\delta>0$; it is claimed that for sufficiently small $|w-w^*|$, the region (in the $z$-plane) satisfying: $$\frac{1}{1+\delta} < \frac{z-w}{z-w^*} < 1+\delta$$
contains $w_0$. How do I show this?

My idea was that the region defined by $\frac{z-w}{z-w^*}<t$ (for positive $t \neq 1$) is bounded by a circle whose radius is $f(t) \cdot |w-w^*|$, $f$ satisfying $f(t) = f(\frac{1}{t})$ (not difficult to show it using Moebius transformations). The region is the interior of the disc if $0<t<1$, and the exterior otherwise (because the expression tends to $1$ as $z \to \infty$). So the region above is the exterior of two discs centered on the line that passes through $w,w_0,w^*$, whose radii decrease as $|w-w^*| \to 0$. It is also easy to see that $w$ is in one disc and not in the other, while $w^*$ is in the second disc and not in the first one. However, I could not show as of yet that the radii can become small enough, so that the discs do not contain $w_0$. Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do a translation and rotation (if needed), and assume $\;w_0=0\;,\;\;w=t\;,\;\;w^*=-t\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R^+\;$ ? Then we're on the real axis, $\;|w-w^*|=2t\;$ , and we get

$$\frac{z-t}{z+t}=\frac{(z-t)(\overline z+t)}{|z+t|^2}=\frac{|z|^2+2ti\text{ Im}\,z-t^2}{|z+t|^2}$$

Well, now your problem is to show zero is contained in the zone you wrote: is it true that

$$\frac1{1+\delta}<\frac{-t^2}{|t|^2}<1+\delta\;?$$

Unless I missed something, I think the above isn't true...

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I suppose that means that somewhere, an absolute value was dropped. Then it works pretty nicely, and you don't even have to do the translation and rotation, just use the fact that $|w_0-w| = |w_0-w^*|$. Now comes a bit more topological question: if that $w_0$ is on a smooth boundary of a simply connected domain, is it true that for sufficiently small $|w-w^*|$, these inequalities will hold for every $z$ on the boundary (and not just $w_0$)?